# How to use multiple RNN Cells in a single layer?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use multiple GRU cells in my model. BUT NOT IN A STACK FORMAT!
That is, for example, there are 2 types of inputs, namely word sequence and POS feature. I want to feed them into 2 independent GRU cells seperately and then use the outputs to continue the works. As I customize the sequence model, I have to obtain the 2 outputs at each time step.
Now my code is:

```
def create_cell(self, Scope, cell_size):
    with tf.variable_scope(Scope, reuse = None):
        if not self.forward_only and self.dropout_keep_prob < 1.0:
            single_cell = GRUCell(cell_size)
            single_cell = DropoutWrapper(single_cell, input_keep_prob = dropout_keep_prob, output_keep_prob = dropout_keep_prob)
        else:
            single_cell = GRUCell(cell_size)
    return single_cell
```

This is a generator of GRU cells.

```
for type in types:
    grus[type] = self.create_cell(type, size)
    states[type] = grus[type].zero_state(1, tf.float32)
```

And I use a dict to store different GRU for different type of inputs.

```
for step in range(self.max_sequence_length):
    for i in range(len(types)):
        type = types[i]
        curgru = grus[type]
        out, state = curgru(input[:,step,:], states[type])
        states[type] = state
```

However, the first time executing the loop(I mean i == 0) it works. Then when i == 1, line of `out, state = curgru(input[:,step,:], states[type])`raises an error:
`gru_cell/gates/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?`
But I do not want to reuse the GRU cells between different types of inputs. So what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it = = . Function **call**() of GRUCell has a parameter of 'scope', I assign the same variable scope as the curgru to it.